# How erlang ling is communicating with xen

Tags: erlang

please could you explain to me an architecture of the LING platform? I don't understand how ling interacts with xen and then with hw - is ling vm talking to xen microkernel directly though c api?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an in-depth knowledge of the project but I think I can give you some pointers for further research.

1) concept of unikernel: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2566628

2) a podcast about this project: http://mostlyerlang.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/020-erlang-on-xen.mp3

From what I understand, based on the unikernel concept, LING has rewritten part of erlang/otp to improve the startup time and remove OS attack vectors. It also translates BEAM files to a custom instrument set.

Answer (score 0):

LING communicates with Xen using 'hypercalls'. The hypercalls mostly used during inital configuration, such as setting page tables. Later the communication with virtual devices happens mostly through shared pages and (soft) interrupts. This is exactly the interface paravirtualised Linux kernel is using when running as Xen guest.